# How does MongoDB Treat Mixed Types?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, datatypes

I'm messing around with mongodb and noticed I can create mixed data types.

```
db.getSiblingDB("bermuda").getCollection("test").insertOne({
    "profile": {
        "t1": 100
    }
});

db.getSiblingDB("bermuda").getCollection("test").insertOne({
    "profile": {
        "t1": "test"
    }
});
```

Which results in:
[image: x]

But because `"t1": 100` was written first, DataGrip thinks that this is an int column. I can query these results both ways.

```
SELECT * FROM bermuda.test
WHERE profile.t1 = 'test'
;

SELECT * FROM bermuda.test
WHERE profile.t1 = 100
;

SELECT * FROM bermuda.test
WHERE profile.t1 > 0
;
```

This raises a lot of questions.

1. Does Mongodb consider this this to be an Int32, String, both, or some kind of "Any" type?
2. How does this affect indexing?
3. Is there a way to get a collections "schema" or is it just looking at the first document in that collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Schema Validation**

You can specify [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) on the document's within a collection to validate the kind of data types you can insert or update for each field. In addition, you can also set other constraints like a required field. This feature will allow you maintain a specific data type for a field. Note that Schema Validation is optional.

**Field Types**

By default, MongoDB number data types are of type `double`. There are other number types like `int`, `long`, `float` and `NumberDecimal`. You can convert the types within your queries as per your requirement. There are various ***operators for the conversion*** from one type to another (including conversion of numbers within strings and vice-versa). [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) is one such operator.

There are also operators to ***check the data type*** is of specific type, before or during processing.

Query operator [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) example, finds documents where the `price` field type is *string*:

```
db.items.find( { price: { $type: "string" } } )
```

Aggregate operator [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) example, gets all documents with a new field telling the data type of a specific field:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { price_type: { $type: "$price" } } }
])
```

**Notes**:

Having mixed data types is something one comes across due to data feeds from various sources or systems. I suspect you need to handle these as needed - identifying and handling at some stage of the application. Regarding indexing on mixed types, I think there are indexing features you can take advantage of based upon your situation: [Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) and [Partial Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/).

Comment: MongoDB''s Compass, a GUI tool to access and work with the database, has a feature to view the present schema of a collection; see [Analyze Your Data Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/schema/).